# Get address from public key in Solidity

Tags: addresses, public-key, assembly

The address is the last 20 bytes of `sha3(publicKey)`

In Solidity, using assembly if needed, how could I splice the first 12 bytes from `sha3(publicKey)` and get the address? What I came up with runs out of gas:

```
bytes32 b = sha3(publicKey)
address signer;
assembly {
signer := mload(add(b, 0x0c) // skip the first 12 bytes, 0c in hex = 12
}
```

MLOAD(0XAB) loads the word (32 byte) located at the memory address 0XAB. Does my function fail because it is trying to load 20 byte only? Can MLOAD load only 20 byte?

Comment: What you're doing here is loading from memory location `sha3(pk)+12`, which is (very likely) a 256-bit number. You're running out of gas because expanding memory to such high a location eats all of it.

Comment: The "usual" way to achieve what you want is to AND with 0x[12 zero-bytes][20 ff-bytes]. An alternative (commonplace elsewhere in computing) is shifting the input left X bits, then back right X bits (without "rotation") - but the EVM doesn't have shift operations (yet).

Comment: @NoelMaersk That's not what that assembly does. `add(b, 0x0c)` is analogous to pointer arithmetic. (It gives you the location in memory 12 bytes past the beginning of `b`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
return address(keccak256(publicKey) & (2**(8*21)-1));
```

`2**(8*21)-1` is just a trick to get 0xFFFFFF... (40 Fs) without typing it. :-)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @schnorr, there's no need for the mask:

```
return address(keccak256(publicKey));
```

Comment: return address(keccak256(_publicKey)); also works, how come it does not include the first 12 byte of the publickey-hash?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense too. `address` is of size 20 bytes, so it can't store more bytes than that. It keeps the least significant bytes, like all casts to smaller-size numbers.

Comment: Isn't the public key 64 bytes? How does this work?

Comment: A public key in Ethereum is 32 bytes, but why does that matter? (`keccak256` always returns 32 bytes.)

Comment: public keys in Ethereum are 64 bytes, not 32! PRIVATE keys are 32 bytes though. Source: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-generate-ethereum-addresses-technical-address-generation-explanation-25r3zqo

Answer (score 1):

From an answer to [How to convert an bytes to address in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30308) as well an answer to [How to concatenate a bytes32[] array to a string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1104), I came up with this for converting a `bytes32 keyHash` to an address.

```
function getAddressFromPublicKey(bytes _publicKey) returns (address signer) {
    // Get address from public key
    bytes32 keyHash = keccak256(_publicKey);
    uint result = 0;
    for (uint i = keyHash.length-1; i+1 > 12; i--) {
      uint c = uint(keyHash[i]);
      uint to_inc = c * ( 16 ** ((keyHash.length - i-1) * 2));
      result += to_inc;
    }
    return address(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In solidity 0.5:

```
function calculateAddress(bytes memory pub) public pure returns (address addr) {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(pub);
    assembly {
        mstore(0, hash)
        addr := mload(0)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for Solidity 0.5.x:

```
bytes32 hash = keccak256(publicKey);
address wallet = address(uint160(bytes20(hash)));
```