# Convert 64 byte public key to 20 byte address in Solidity

Tags: solidity, addresses, public-key

I am trying to convert a 128 characters hex encoded public key to an address in Solidity (0.5).

For example the pubkey would be:

`af80b90d25145da28c583359beb47b21796b2fe1a23c1511e443e7a64dfdb27d7434c380f0aa4c500e220aa1a9d068514b1ff4d5019e624e7ba1efe82b340a59`

which should generate an address of:

`0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57`

How to convert a 64 byte public key to a 20 byte address in Solidity?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/get-address-from-public-key-in-solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```solidity
function publicKeyToAddress (bytes memory publicKey) public pure returns (bytes20) {
    require (publicKey.length == 64);
    return bytes20 (uint160 (uint256 (keccak256 (publicKey))));
}
```

In Remix it gives me:

**Input:**

```
{
    "bytes publicKey": "0xaf80b90d25145da28c583359beb47b21796b2fe1a23c1511e443e7a64dfdb27d7434c380f0aa4c500e220aa1a9d068514b1ff4d5019e624e7ba1efe82b340a59"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "0": "bytes20: 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57"
}
```