# Solidity: Convert hex-string variable into bytes

Tags: solidity, bytes

I am looking for an option to efficiently convert a string passed to a function as a parameter, interpreted as hex, into `bytes`. In Solidity.

I.e. doing the same that this piece of code would do

```
bytes memory b = hex"abcdef1234567890";
```

just with a string passed as a parameter for a function.

```
contract C {
  function f(string memory s) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory b;
    ... // read hex-string into b
    return b;
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd want something that isn't "manually" looping through the characters of the string in order to translate each into a byte individually as described here: [Solidity convert hex string to bytes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39989/solidity-convert-hex-string-to-bytes). Unfortunately, I can't do this off-chain.

Is there such a way?

Comment: What's the reason why you can't do this off chain? As I explained in your previous question, it's a lot more efficient to do it there.

Comment: I have an external app I cannot change that will send a string

Comment: I don't think you can avoid iterating all characters there's no opcode to do that, but the solution in the link can be improved by writing in assembly and removing the bound checks. But I'm with Morten here, it should be done off-chain it will be cheaper in the long run.

Comment: how could/would that be done in assembly?