# How to derive an ETH Address from a PublicKey?

Tags: solidity, addresses, public-key

I wrote a small contract that is supposed to generate an `address` from a given `publicKey`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GenerateAddress {
    bytes public publicKey = "6d7bac197da6e91f506db699a1844efc93b9bf5508bacb6870a98fc2137c4330741f94af61aa635a44f9059ff2082737d43cfb376124ae8772250b85f656aa1d";

    function generateAddress() public view returns (address addr) {
        bytes32 publicKeyHash = keccak256(publicKey);
        addr = address(bytes20(publicKeyHash));
        return addr;
    }

}
```

The public key in question was generated from this page: [Ethereum Address Generator](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/ethadd)
(Been using it for years to get some test addresses etc.)

[image: Generate ETH address]

So I hard-coded the `publicKey` I got from there to test my simple contract.

However the address I got is `0x70191eCc889463533ea48C3A666e7eE0692a0087` while the `Ethereum Address Generator` returns `0xdf92c554c0078eec90937d7a5944976ef31d602c` as valid address (For the **same** public key)

Basically, I get **different** `address` for **identical** `publicKey` and I would like to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addr = address(bytes20(publicKeyHash));` is taking the first 20 bytes - for an address you need the last 20

also, solidity is taking `publicKey` as a string and converting it to bytes (using utf-8 encoding). you need to save it as a hexadecimal number (or convert it to bytes first, then hardcode it)

Edit: the answer here explains it in full - [Compute address of public key string in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101994/compute-address-of-public-key-string-in-solidity?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In your smart contract there are some issues:

- When you're calculating the account hash you must pass your public key like hexedecimal value. In your case, you're executing this operation with the literal value.
- For calculating account address, you must take the **20 bytes** == **40 characters** from the ending of hash public key value (in your case `publicKeyHash`). With this statement, address(bytes20(publicKeyHash)); you're taking **40 characters** from the variable beginning.

To fix this issues, I modified your smart contract in this way and put some notes:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GenerateAddress {
    // NOTE: With hex before the value, Solidity compiler takes this value in hexadecimal value
    bytes public publicKey = hex"6d7bac197da6e91f506db699a1844efc93b9bf5508bacb6870a98fc2137c4330741f94af61aa635a44f9059ff2082737d43cfb376124ae8772250b85f656aa1d";

    function generateAddress() public view returns (address addr) {
        bytes32 publicKeyHash = keccak256(publicKey);
        // NOTE: I take the last 40 characters from the end of publicKeyHash variable 
        //       and convert them into address.
        addr = address(uint160(uint256(publicKeyHash)));
        return addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already solved this issue, but I got caught up on something else, so I forgot to answer to accept an answer. Your explanation is good, but some details/numbers are off, so I will edit your answer to fix it. Hope that is ok with you.

Comment: Sure, we should always improve answers to make them helpful to other users that they have the same issue or doubt

Comment: hex"" != bytes("")