# Convert bytes32 to address

Tags: solidity, addresses, bytes32

Is there a simple way to convert a bytes32, e.g. `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c`, to an address?

```
bytes32 data = "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c";
```

I tried casting it with `address(data)` but that didn't work. I've also seen [this solution here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/how-to-convert-an-bytes-to-address-in-solidity) but that only works with `bytes` and not `bytes32`.

Here's the function I need in solidity:

```
function bytes32ToAddress(bytes32 input) public pure returns(address){
   // convert input to address
   return ...;
}
```

Comment: at the end of 2022 implicit conversion is not allowed anymore, but explicit conversion should be possible https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/126050/23579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine. Perhaps you were actually including single quotes in your code? If so, remove them.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    function test(bytes32 data) external pure returns (address) {
        return address(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I edited the question. I want to convert a bytes32 element to an address.

Comment: So you have a string with a hexadecimal representation of an address in it? Why?

Comment: Or if the double quotes are again a mistake, see my edited code. Converting from `bytes32` to `address` is straightforward, but if you actually have a string, that's another matter.

Comment: I have a function that accepts a bytes32 element. I don't know how to represent a bytes32 element inline. I just put it inside the remix-function in quotes. To be honest I don't even know what bytes32 is.

Comment: I made another edit to accept the `bytes32` as a parameter. In any case, it all works the same. If you have a `bytes32`, you can just cast it to `address`.

Comment: To pass a `bytes32` in Remix, make sure to pad it appropriately. E.g. type `0x000000000000000000000000ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c`.

Comment: Ah I see! I missed the padding part. Now it works. Thank you! Do you have ressources to learn about bytes32? The [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html) doesn't give much information.

Comment: `bytes32` is just 32 bytes.

Comment: I see. Sorry for beeing a noob.

Comment: Hey everyone, reopening the issue almost a year later, but when trying your code @smarx, I got this error: `TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "address".`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I assume you're using Solidity 0.5.x. There's another answer to this question that gives code for 0.5.x.

Answer (score 10):

For solidity 0.5.x you can use

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test {
    function test(bytes32 data) external pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(data)));
    }
}
```

First convert the bytes32 to a uint256, later to uint160(20 bytes) and finaly to addres, this use big endian.

If you want use little endian you should use `address(uint160(bytes20(b)))`

For more information: [solidity doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
assembly {
    mstore(0, hash)
    addr := mload(0)
}
```

Here is an example how to convert public key into address this way: [Get address from public key in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/get-address-from-public-key-in-solidity/63558#63558)

Answer (score 1):

> If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an address, for example bytes32, then the address is truncated. To reduce conversion ambiguity version 0.4.24 and higher of the compiler force you make the truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example the address 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC.
> You can use address(uint160(bytes20(b))), which results in 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa, or you can use address(uint160(uint256(b))), which results in 0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.9/types.html#address