# Convert bytes20 to address in assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes, convert

Can you convert a `bytes20` to `address` in assembly (not solidity-typecasting)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

If the address is in the first bytes, you can do:

```js
assembly {
    parsed := shr(96, mload(add(data, 32)))
}
```

With this, you right-shift 96 bits (or 12 bytes), and then assign to an `address` type.

This solution won't work if you assign to a `bytes20` because `bytes20` grabs the highest bytes while `address` the lowest.

Comment: Nice  yeah that byte placement dependant on type being passed got me. Thanks too 

Answer (score 0):

Yep, heres an example of what the function might look like:

```
function convertBytes20ToAddress(bytes bytesInput) internal returns (address addressOutput) {
    assembly {
      addressOutput := mload(add(bytesInput,20))
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're just leaving an offset of 20 bytes before loading to memory the next 32, so you'd be getting here 12 bytes of 0 left-padding (the rest of the length of the bytes array) plus some of the actual data

Comment: Read this thread https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/how-to-convert-an-bytes-to-address-in-solidity - where someone actually did pretty much the same as me, but others ran into errors in the process and used a different assembly structure. Wdyt?

Comment: This one works (from your link): 

assembly {
    parsed := shr(96, mload(add(data, 32)))
}
.
I found the answer a couple of days ago, but forgot to update it here. Doing that right now.